# In R, select elements from a column if they occupy the same row as elements of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, subset

This question has likely been asked elsewhere, but since I'm new to R and my vocabulary is limited, I can't seem to find it.

If I have a character-filled data frame, say:

```
c1 <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee")
c2 <- c("ff", "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj")
c3 <- c("kk", "ll", "mm", "nn", "oo")
c4 <- c("pp", "qq", "rr", "ss", "tt")
c5 <- c("uu", "vv", "ww", "xx", "yy")
df <- cbind.data.frame(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
```

resulting in

```
  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1 aa ff kk pp uu
2 bb gg ll qq vv
3 cc hh mm rr ww
4 dd ii nn ss xx
5 ee jj oo tt yy
```

And I want to select elements out of column 4 that occupy the same row as multiple elements out of column 2 (say, "gg", "ii", and "jj"), is there a way to do this without using a different command for each one?

For example,

```
df$c4[i = c(2,4,5)]
```

will return

```
[1] qq ss tt
Levels: pp qq rr ss tt
```

and

```
df$c4[df$c2 == "gg"]
```

will return

```
[1] qq
Levels: pp qq rr ss tt
```

but when I try to combine the two with

```
df$c4[i = c(df$c2=="gg", df$c2=="ii", df$c2=="jj")]
```

R seems to only partially know what to do, returning

```
[1] qq   <NA> <NA>
Levels: pp qq rr ss tt
```

Comment: This `df$c4[df$c2 %in% c("gg", "ii", "jj")]` works, it gives `[1] qq ss tt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you really want to accomplish but in your last line, this is what you are actually doing:

```
> df$c4[i = c(df$c2=="gg", df$c2=="ii", df$c2=="jj")]
[1] "qq" NA   NA  
> i = c(df$c2=="gg", df$c2=="ii", df$c2=="jj")
> i
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> df$c2
[1] "ff" "gg" "hh" "ii" "jj"
```

You are passing a length `15` logical vector to a `5` length character vector, which does not make much sense.

Comment: Thank you!!  For an absolute beginner like me, it is easy to think about things like `[]` as a black box, forgetting what I'm actually doing.  Your response made me think about how I need to pass a length 5 logical vector, which made me realize that the code I'm looking for is `df$c4[df$c2=="gg" | df$c2=="ii" | df$c2=="jj"]` - pretty basic